# Default button setting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page that contains two buttons one is "btnCancel" and another one is "btnSave".

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);" ValidationGroup="grp"/>
```

Now the problem is after filling up some of the textboxes which are present in that page, if I press the "Enter button" the "btnCancel_Click" event is firing instead of "btnSave_Click".

Can any one please suggest me how to set the "btnSave_Click" button as the default one. So that if any one press the "enter button" it will fire the "btnSave_Click" event.

Any help please.

Updated Question:

```
    <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSave" runat="server" ID="pnlTest">
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
                                            OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);" ValidationGroup="grp" />
   </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I used the code given below:
this.Form.DefaultButton = btnSave.UniqueID;
It is working fine. So, it can be an alternate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your form controls inside asp.net Panel and set `DefaultButton` to your button id
Example:

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSave">    
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click"OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false,true);" ValidationGroup="grp"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Did u add all other controls like textboxes and labels inside the same panel? It should work if all of your controls are in the panels and not the buttons only. try it and feed me back

Comment: Yes it is now working fine. Thanks a lot for your time and support.

Answer (score 6):

Set the `defaultbutton` attribute on the containing `panel`:

```
<asp:panel defaultbutton=“btnSave”>
```

Taken from [this blogpost](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/04/421647.aspx).

Comment: This page does not contain any panel and it inherit a master page.

Comment: Then add both buttons to a panel, as suggested by Pr0fess0rX.

Comment: could you add to your question your new code, the two buttons and the wrapping panel?

Comment: Looks correct. Try setting the `defaultfocus` (asp 2.0) attribute on the containing `form` tag. There is a section about it in the post I linked.

Comment: @mizipzor Yes it is now working fine. Thanks a lot for your time and support.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > 
function button_click(objTextBox,objBtnID)
{
    if(window.event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById(objBtnID).focus();
        document.getElementById(objBtnID).click();
    }
}
</script>
```

add this in your page load event

```
this.TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "button_click(this,'" + this.btnSave.ClientID + "')");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep it in mind, this will be helpful in some other cases.

Answer (score 0):

we can set the "defaultbutton" property in the form tag

Answer (score 0):

set this javascript to header

```
function checkKey(b1, e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    //alert(e.keyCode + 'validation.js');
    document.getElementById(b1).click();
    return false;
}
```

}

and set attributes to control

```
txtboxname.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:return checkKey('" + buttonName.ClientID + "',event);");
```